# Modify article on the fly in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I can change a title by placing the next line into my template:

```
$doc->setTitle('my new title');
```

But is any method to modify an article's 'fulltext' in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, with a [content plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content).

### Details

If you can use `$doc->setTitle()`, I assume that somewhere before that line there's a line which says:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
```

But the **document** refers to the **whole page**, so you're actually setting the html `<title>` tag.

If you want to change an **article** text, you're dealing with the result of a specific component, i.e. `com_content`, which is only a part of the whole document.

There are more than one ways to change it.

### Change the whole page content

If you want to change the whole page content in your template, you have to do:

```
$buffer = $doc->getBuffer();
// ... do whatever modification to buffer
$doc->setBuffer($buffer)
```

Quite simple to do, but it's not a good idea to put this kind of logic in the template (if you ever want to change your template, you'll have to copy / paste the code).

### Use a system plugin to change the buffer

The core of this solution is the same as before, but you put the logic in a **system plugin**, hooking on the `onAfterRender` event. You get the buffer, you modify it, you set the buffer.

Good solution for very simple modifications and/or if you want to make sure the modifications applies to **any** part of the page.

### Use a content plugin

A **content plugin** applies only to articles body, product descriptions, and similar text parts.

You should use this if you want only to modify those parts.